# Move slide automatically when video ends in owl carousel

Tags: jquery, video, owl-carousel

I have implemented video and image carousel using owl carousel. The you tube video is added in the first slide. I want to move the slide as soon as the video ends. 
    As the video is added in the first slide can we autoplay the video as soon as the slide appears everytime.

JavaScript Code:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
                            items:1,
                            merge:true,
                            loop:true,
                            margin:10,
                            nav:true,
                            autoplay:true,
                            autoplayTimeout:140000,
                            video:true,
                            videoHeight: 520, 
                            videoWidth: 1000,
                            lazyLoad:false,
                            center:true,
                            autoHeight:true
                        });
```

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
<div class="item-video" >
<a class="owl-video"  href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/F0vg4HUEIyk"></a>
</div>
<div class="item"><img src="1.jpg"/></div>
<div class="item"><img src="2jpg"/></div>
<div class="item"><img src="3.jpg"/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Title asks one, your question other stuff :) Does youtube API provides an `onended` event? Does owlCarousel offers handing custom events? Yes? What have you tried?

Comment: I want to slide the carousel to next slide as soon as the youtube video which is included in the first slide [<a class="owl-video"  href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/F0vg4HUEIyk"></a>] ends playing.